# Can't do http post/get request between 2 local apps with angular-cli

Tags: angular, django-rest-framework, angular-httpclient, angular-cli-v6

I totally discover angular 6 with the tutorial and I would try to ask a djangorestframework backend api with an angular-cli frontend.

It's look like my frontend only send an OPTIONS request to the back (according to the Mozilla's network tab).
I tried accessing to data with postman tool and I get a correct response from my backend.

I got this error on my console tab: `ERROR Object { headers: Object, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: null, ok: false, name: "HttpErrorResponse", message: "Http failure response for (unknown …", error: error }`

Before you ask I set `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"` to remove CORS error, but I still can't access to my backend data.

Here is my frontend code:
domain-analyse.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { DomainAnalyse} from './domain-analyse';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

import {ANALYSES}   from './mock-analyse'
import { Domain } from 'domain';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DomainAnalyseService {
  private urlBase = 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1.0/analyse/' 
  public domainList: DomainAnalyse[]
  getDomainSpecificAnalyse (domain, analyse) {
    const body = {'domain': domain}
    const urlCalled = this.urlBase+analyse
    return this.http.post(urlCalled, body);
  }
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
}
```

domain-analyse.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Router, ActivatedRoute, Params} from '@angular/router';

import { DomainAnalyseService } from '../domain-analyse.service';
import { DomainAnalyse }        from '../domain-analyse'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-domain-analyse',
  templateUrl: './domain-analyse.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./domain-analyse.component.css']
})
export class DomainAnalyseComponent implements OnInit {

  public domain: DomainAnalyse

  constructor(
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private domainAnalyseService: DomainAnalyseService
  ) { }

  analyseDomain (domain, analyse): Object {
      return this.domainAnalyseService.getDomainSpecificAnalyse(domain, analyse).subscribe(
        (analyse: DomainAnalyse) => this.domain = {...analyse}
      );
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // subscribe to router event
    this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      this.analyseDomain(params.domain, params.analyse)
    });
  }

}
```

domain-analyse.ts

```
export class DomainAnalyse{
    constructor(
        public name: string,
        public analyse: string,
        public url: string,
        public date: string,
        public grading: Grading,
    ){}
}

export class Grading{
    constructor(
        public score: number,
        public grade: string,
        public color: string,
        public analyse_type: string,
        public displayable_element: Displayable[],
    ){}
}

export class Displayable{
    constructor(
        public score: number,
        public symbole: string,
        public color: string
    ){}
}
```

If something is missing I can add it to the post.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Try the same using Google Chrome. Close all chrome instances and start a new instance with the following command chrome --disable-web-security --user-data-dir=C:\Chrome

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide the .har file of the network log? (using chrome) right click any network request, and say "save as har with content" then upload that, somewhere we can access it.

Comment: You can have it [here](https://framadrop.org/r/m0dTqFtgqk#keCx3yRl8PqbUPhdVp1LUOsl817oAZthhGoICL3/vv4=)